# How to convert multiple select checkbox values into an item List inside a form array in Angular?

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot, angular-material

I am developing a CRUD application of Employee management system. I use Angular, Angular Material, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL for this. There are two tables Employee and Skills in database which are mapped using Many to Many mapping. So the Employee is having a List of Skills. I have used an Angular form in frontend to enter these values to the database. For the Skill entry I used a FormArray since it is a list of skills in backend.

Here is the html code part which I wrote when skills property is considered as a formControl.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Skills*</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="skills" multiple>
            <mat-select-trigger>
              {{employeeService.form.controls['skills'].value ? employeeService.form.controls['skills'].value[0] : ''}}
              <span *ngIf="employeeService.form.controls['skills'].value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
                (+{{employeeService.form.controls['skills'].value.length - 1}} {{employeeService.form.controls['skills'].value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
              </span>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.id">{{skill.skill_name}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error>This field is mandatory. Select at least one</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Since I need a list of skills, I made skills to FormArray. Here is the code part.

```
export class EmployeeService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: new FormControl(null),
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dob: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.email, Validators.required]),
      skills: new FormArray([]),
    });

    initializeFormGroup() {
      this.form.setValue({
        id: null,
        name: '',
        dob: '',
        email: '',
        skills: '',
      });
    }
```

Structure of the data is as below.

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "User1",
    "dob": "2021-04-02T18:30:00.000+00:00",
    "email": "user1@abc.com",
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "skill_name": "Backend Developer"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "skill_name": "Frontend Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I have no idea of how to use FormArray in html code to send the items selected in multiple checkbox to the database as a list.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible to create a stackblitz of the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are' using mat-select multiple. A mat-select-multiple return an array, so you **needn't** use a FormArray, just a simple formControl.

Yes!, a FormControl can store an array

But you're using a mat-select to store an array of object, so first you need make a function "compare with". It's only a function that return true if the "id"s are equals

```
compareSkills=(o1:any,o2:any)=>o1.id==o2.id
```

And you also need that, in mat-select show the "skills_name" selected. In this case you use a new function getter:

```
  get skillsTxt()
  {
    const value=this.form && this.form.get('skills')?this.form.get('skills').value:null
    return value ? value.map((x:any)=>x.skill_name).join(","): ''
  }
```

With all this, our mat-select should be:

```
<mat-select formControlName="Skills" multiple [compareWith]="compareSkills">
     <mat-select-trigger>
         {{skillsTxt}}
     </mat-select-trigger>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill">
         {{skill.skill_name}}
     </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

**IMPORTANT** about your code:

You are mixing formBuilder and constructor of form controls. Take a look how create a formGroup

```
  //using the "constructors":
  this.form=new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(null),
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dob: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.email, Validators.required]),
      skills: new FormControl([])
   })

  //using formBuilder: -see that we not use new FormControl
  this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      dob: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
      skills: [[]]
   })
```

Well really it's better create a function to create the form

```
getForm(data:any=null){
 data=data || {id:0,name:null,dob:null,email:null:skills:[]}
 return this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [data.id,Validators.required],
    name: [data.name, Validators.required],
    dob: [data.dob, Validators.required],
    email: [data.email, [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    skills: [data.skills]
 });
```

}

So, you can use in ngOnInit

```
   ngOnInit(){
      this.form=this.getForm() //create a empty form
   }
```

or, is you has a service that return an object

```
   ngOnInit(){
      this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe((res:any)=>{
          this.form=this.getForm(res);  //create a form with the "data"
      })
   }
```